# Hypothesis for $L^2$ to be an Hilbert space?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a measure space, is there hypothesis on $\mu$ for $L^2(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ to be Hilbert with
$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_X f \overline{g}\ \mathrm{d}\mu.$$

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: No hypothesis on $\mu$: Notice that $ab\leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$ for all $a,b\geq 0$ implies $|f\overline g|\leq \frac 12\big(|f|^2+|g|^2\big)$. That is to say,  $f,g\in L^2(\mu)\implies f\overline g\in L^1(\mu)$.

Comment: Oh thank you, I can't prove that $\int f d\mu = 0$ then $f = 0$ a.e... Here http://mathonline.wikidot.com/integral-criteria-for-functions-to-be-zero-almost-everywhere they use the fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite

Comment: You need to show, $||f||_2:=\displaystyle\sqrt{\displaystyle\int_X|f|^2\ \mathrm d\mu}=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e., see the definition of norm.

Comment: Yes, I forget to write that $f$ is non negative. I wanted to show something stronger so, which false in general, right ?

Comment: Here https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf at page 2, they ask $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite. Does this hypothesis is needed for general $p$ ?

Comment: @ValentinDusollier No hypotheses are needed. $L^2(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is always a Hilbert space. Completeness comes from completeness of $L^p$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$. The inner product axioms are easy to verify, the hardest one to prove being $(f, f) = 0 \implies f = 0$ a.e. (which is already verified when proving $L^p$ is a normed vector space).

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! :D